# Java: Deleting file after download using PHP

Tags: java, php, android

I am currently developing an android app to download a file from server after which I need to delete it.

I've done a bit of Google and most of the solutions was to use the apache FTPClient. I personally prefer to use PHP to do the job but I have some concerns.

Can I and more importantly SHOULD I use PHP to delete said files? I would be passing the filename as POST data and not Query Strings. Will this be secure enough so people are unable to mess with my file system? Or will I need to watch out for other stuff

Comment: You want to delete the just downloaded file? Why? Why did you download if you delete it right away?

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear. I meant deleting the server file not the local file

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the php and i have not tried this but you should try this. Before downloading the file, get filename and store it in variable. Now after downloading file, search that file in the database and fire the query for deleting it.